# How to get all URLs from browser Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, browser

I need to get all the URLs in my browser which is currently open, (*not opening a browser with selenium and getting that link*) is it possible? All the info available on StackOverflow are about getting the links from a selenium browser. But I need the links from my current browser which is open right now.

I tried:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/User Data/Default/History')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('select url from urls where id > 390')
print(cur.fetchall())
```

But I get this error:

```
cur.execute('select url from urls where id > 390')
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

• Windows 10

• Brave browser (Version 1.28.105 Chromium: 92.0.4515.131)

• Python 3.9 (64-bit)

**NOTE: I WANT LINKS FROM MY BROWSER NOT FROM A WEBSITE**

Comment: What browser? What operating system? Does it need to be Python? On a Mac, for example, this is probably possible with at least some browsers using AppleScript. On a Windows system I bet you could do it using AutoHotkey. You could write Python wrappers around either of those.

Comment: I use brave on windows,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All webkit based browsers (brave, vivaldi, chrome, ...) use a history database in `sqlite3` format, so you could connect to the database using Python:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(
    # Path on my Mac, there must be a equivalent on Windows.
    '/Users/foobar/Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Default/History'
)
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('select url from urls where id > 390')
print(cur.fetchall())
```

Out:

```
[('https://cybernews.com/how-to-use-vpn/change-google-play-country/',), ('https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android+change+coutnry&t=bravened',), ('https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android+change+coutnry&t=bravened&ia=web',) ...
```

Alternatively:

Write your own Chrome extension, which allows you listen all URL changes and can be saved somewhere on your local machine.

Comment: cur.execute('select url from urls where id > 390')
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
what should i do i found out that file but I get this error

Comment: by the way, i only want the currently open tabs URL, not the whole history

Comment: This is the path to that file in windows. C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/User Data/Default/History

Comment: @Johan Jomy: I dont know if that approach fits all your needs, it's just one way that *could* work.